# How to install Epson L220 scanner on Lubuntu

Tags: 16.04

Sorry for my English,

Im newbie user for Lubuntu, im already install printer's driver (Epson L220) and its success, but i dont understand how to install scanner's driver, can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Typically, Linux should come with most scan drivers out-of-the-box.

If your scanner is actually not working, follow these steps:

1. Download the Scanner Drivers from [Epson](http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php?version=1.1.9).
2. Extract the deb file from the downloaded archive.
3. Open a terminal and type `sudo dpkg -i </path/to/file.deb>`. Hit Enter.
4. Take whatever steps DPKG deems necessary (usually running `sudo apt -f install`).

Afterwards, your scanner driver should have been installed.

Comment: Thanks, but i still cannot install im use this command "sudo dpkg -i <home/it/imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.04-1.1.9.x68.deb" is it correct?

Comment: the answer is  "No such file or directory"

Comment: Get rid of the < and > and it should be fine

Comment: Im already doing this following steps  "sudo dpkg -i /home/it/downloads/imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.04-1.1.9.x86.deb
[sudo] password for it: 
"

Comment: The answer was "dpkg: error processing archive /home/it/downloads/imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.04-1.1.9.x86.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/it/downloads/imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.04-1.1.9.x86.deb"

Comment: Use a capital D in Downloads, Linux is case sensitive

Comment: I did this following command "sudo dpkg -i /home/it/Downloads/imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.04-1.1.9.x86.deb" but the answer is "dpkg-split: error: error reading /home/it/Downloads/imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.04-1.1.9.x86.deb: Is a directory
dpkg:../../src/unpack.c:123:deb_reassemble: internal error: unexpected exit status 2 from dpkg-split" and error message come in "Sorry, the application has stop unexpectedly" is my Lubuntu corrupt?

Comment: Try removing .tar.gz from the downloaded file's name, and try installing that. If that fails, I will look into this tomorrow with a bit more effort, as it's rather late here.

Comment: Okay kaz, thanks so much for helping me, i will try it. Terima Kasih Banyak